# How to find out which application or service uses virtualization (AMD-V or VT-x) in Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to run a virtual machine in VirtualBox, but it gives me the following error:

VBoxManage.exe: error: AMD-V is being used by another hypervisor. (VERR_SVM_IN_USE).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VirtualBox can't enable the AMD-V extension. Please close all other virtualization programs. (VERR_SVM_IN_USE)

Is is possible to find out which program or service exactly has taken control of virtualization, so that I can uninstall it?

Comment: Most likely hyper-v. Have you checked that it is disabled?

Comment: This PC is running Windows 7 x64 which does seem to have Hyper-V. But I have recently installed latest NVIDIA graphics drivers. Can these drivers somehow interfere with VirtualBox?

Comment: No, graphics drivers won't interfere. If I'm not mistaken Android Studio can also cause this. Do you have that installed?

Comment: there are various applications that use virtualization which will enable Hyper-V like Docker or MSVC. The easiest solution would be enabling nested virtualization